# How to search for categories instead of products in Woocommerce?

Tags: search, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a webshop with over 30.000 products. I was wondering whether it was possible to, when you search to do so that it searches for categories, rather than products as I get a ton of products when I search for something, I would rather search for categories instead.

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce provides these kind of functionality. Some of the links which you can use as a reference

[WooCommerce Product Search](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/widgets/)